# Asp Net Boilerplate - why it auto set isEmailConfirmed is true

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I using Asp Net Boilerplate to create API for website. And I have problem when publish it to server. Sometimes the user account is set isEmailConfirmed = true without confirmation email or setting this property?
I don't know the reason why. Could you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's set to `true` in [`UserAppService.Create`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/3d6927b5034feb098d5f8b446398c16b87eb072a/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/Users/UserAppService.cs#L52) method:

```
user.IsEmailConfirmed = true;
```

You can change that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [AccountAppService.Register()](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/Authorization/Accounts/AccountAppService.cs).

It is set to `true` by default as well.